# Are batch mutations atomic in Cassandra?

Tags: cloud, cassandra, key-value

The Cassandra API supports batch mutations:

> **batch_mutate(keyspace, mutation_map,
>   consistency_level)**: Executes the
>   specified mutations on the keyspace.
>   mutation_map is a map>>; the
>   outer map maps the key to the inner
>   map, which maps the column family to
>   the Mutation; can be read as: map>>. To be more specific,
>   the outer map key is a row key, the
>   inner map key is the column family
>   name. A Mutation specifies either
>   columns to insert or columns to
>   delete. See Mutation and Deletion
>   above for more details.

Are all mutations that are executed in a batch executed atomically? So if one of the mutations fails, do the others fail too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything associated w/ a given key is atomic (which is why batch_mutate allows multiple CFs w/ a single key).

Comment: The key should be same but can the batch insert be different for 2 different CF's. The key remains same but the column(name , value) is different ? WIll it support that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662657/astyanax-if-a-mutationbatch-fails-halfway-what-guarantees-do-i-have , here you have answered that even for different keys it will be atomic, as the OP has asked about multiple rows in multiple column families . 
Can i insert to different rows in different CF , and expect if some succesds , all will get succeeded ?

Comment: Read the article I linked in that post: multi-key atomicity is guaranteed in 2013; it was not in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

All mutations for a given key are atomic but there is no isolation on reads. 
Besides that there are no more guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra 1.2-beta1 added support for [atomic batch update](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=CHANGES.txt;hb=refs/tags/cassandra-1.2.0-beta1), [here too](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS.txt;hb=refs/tags/cassandra-1.2.0-beta1)...

> - Atomic batches are now supported server side, where Cassandra will
>      guarantee that (at the price of pre-writing the batch to another node
>      first), all mutations in the batch will be applied, even if the
>      coordinator fails mid-batch.